# Hay una manera de decir "hombre del Renacimiento" a una mujer?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones

Me he preguntado si hay una forma neutral de "hombre del Renacimiento" que se puede decir de una mujer en finés o inglés. No he encontrando nada pero he visto que la misma expresión existe en español. Conociendo a la gente aquí, pienso que sois capaces de encontrar algo.

Cosas como 'persona / humano del Renacimiento' suenan demasiado (por usar algo que he aprendido recientemente) macarrónico.

Comment: Yo he oído, y me parece muy bien (aunque no es una traducción literal): *mujer orquesta*.  Creo que esto es equivalente a *one-man band* pero obviamente ajustado a la mujer que logra hacer todo.  Ejemplo: Raquel es una mujer orquesta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En principio, si solo quieres una versión femenina, *mujer del Renacimiento* / *mujer renacentista* se dice y se entiende sin problema.

Si buscas algo que se puede aplicar tanto al hombre como a la mujer, a mí no me suena nada mal decir *persona del Renacimiento*, de hecho, es una frase que se puede encontrar fácilmente por el Internet, e incluso con referencia a hombres justo al lado de su nombre. O se puede decir *persona renacentista*, que también goza de algún uso.

Comment: Preferiría *figura de Renacimiento* o *mujer-orquesta*.

Comment: *Mujer del Renacimiento* no me suena a mí como lo que debería significar, quizá porque todos los ejemplos conocidos de *hombres del Renacimiento* eran, bueno, hombres. Las mujeres no tenían mucha chance de destacarse.

Comment: Perdóname no responder antes. Lo de 'figura de Renacimiento' me gusta a mí, ¿podrías añadirlo? Y gracias para la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

### *Que tal?*

Después de tanto tiempo no se si encontró la respuesta...yo encontré la pregunta hoy.

- Como sabrá el término Renacimiento, como movimiento, data del S. XIX y «Hombre del Renacimiento» solo desde principios del siglo XX. El término utilizado anteriormente para designar a este tipo de eruditos ó sabios, fue "polimata", del griego (polimathos, varios saberes, varias materias), desde principios del S. XVII y anterior a este  polyhistor datado a últimos del S.XVI. La palabra "polímata", aunque no muy utilizada, era y es aún empleada para referirse a cualquier persona erudita, tanto hombre ó mujer, ya pertenezca o no al Renacimiento, así tenemos a la polímata alemana medieval Hildegard von Bingen (1098-1179) de la Orden de San Benito.
- De forma general, incluyendo el concepto de "Hombre del Renacimiento" se utiliza cada vez más el concepto de "**Tratadista**", no solo para referirse a la arquitectura ó la pintura del Renacimiento, sino en un sentido amplio al mismo carácter que se imprime cuando se dice "Hombre del Renacimiento", para nombrar ó relacionar  a  personajes sobresalientes, hombres y mujeres, dentro de este periodo de la historia conocido como Renacimiento.

Otros conceptos;

- En desuso, es «homo universalis», que igualmente se suele interpretar como persona universal.
- Polimatía, poco utilizado.
- Erudito/a Renacentista
- Genio/ Genialidad Renacentista

Espero le haya ayudado. Saludos.

Diego M.